# C# How to detect that which thread is using my function

Tags: c#

I have three threads in my program, one function and 5 .txt files

The function randomly select a file and writes something in it

now my problem is to detect that which thread is use which file

I want show in a rich textbox something like this:

thread one add in 2.txt

thread three add in 1.txt

thread three add in 1.txt

thread three add in 1.txt

thread three add in 5.txt

thread two add in 3.txt

....

**Edit**

I use Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString()  like this:

```
case 4:
                        if (c4 >= 5)
                        {
                            c44 = true;
                            test();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
                            {
                                richTextBox1.Text += "\n\n4--->" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString() + "\n\n";
                            }));
                            writefile(t4);
                        }
                        c4++;
                        test();
                        break;
```

case 4 means my thread is writting in 4.txt

Comment: Thread.currentThread output that too screen

Comment: `my problem is to detect that which thread is use which file` - this is [`Y` problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) and what is `X` ?

Comment: the file is select in a switch case the problem is which thread is in the for example case 2...

Comment: This will give you a unique thread id: `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `Thread.currentThread` you can tell which thread is running the function

```
string temp = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString();
```

Comment: how can I use it? I'm beginner in threading!!!

Comment: @ZoomVirus: Pretty useless to always print "System.Threading.Thread", don't you think?

Comment: @codemonkey well it gives a good indication to a beginner as to where to look for this function...

Comment: I use Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString(); but it always show 8 !!!

Comment: @saminpanahi if you get the same number each time it is the exact same thread each time